# Conditional pivot table filtering (if one is selected disable the other)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Just as the title says, I'm trying to disable or have the opposing filter default to "All" if the other is selected.

For instance I have a pivot table with two filters - "WEEK" and "MONTH"

If someone selects a value in the week filter, i want the month filter to default to "(all)" and vice versa.

Pretty simple but I'm not sure how to attack this (VBA or formula) and furthermore the code.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no event which would trace pivottable field change. Therefore my idea is as follow.
Step 1. Place somewhere public variables:

```
Public tmpM As Boolean
Public tmpW As Boolean
```

Step 2. In the sheet module where your pivottable is placed put the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.PivotFields("week").AllItemsVisible = False And tmpW = True Then
    Target.PivotFields("month").ClearAllFilters
End If
If Target.PivotFields("month").AllItemsVisible = False And tmpM = True Then
    Target.PivotFields("week").ClearAllFilters
End If
tmpM = Target.PivotFields("month").AllItemsVisible
tmpW = Target.PivotFields("week").AllItemsVisible

Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It works fine with my example data.

**Edit:** error handling in code above.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Is there anyway I can reference the cell instead of "week" or "month"? as this value will change depending on selection.

Comment: no, there isn't as we can't read the cell which filter you change. but you could read the pivotfields by their position within table structure. If you always have two fields in row orientation than you could relay on this information.

Comment: Could we do something like
      If Target.PivotFields<>("(all)")

or even a range like If Target.PivotFields("january","february")

Comment: Also i can't seem to get this to work - I've replaced the "Week" and "Month" with values that can be selected via filter("WEEK 3" & "February") and it still does not seem to work for me.

I'm receiving the following error: Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class

Comment: 1. you could go through each PivotField and set each `.ClearAllFilters` if needed. Simple loop would work. 2. I have improved code by adding some error handling instructions. It will work with new fields name anyway. You could have possibly had an error earlier which stopped events handling. Please set `Application.EnableEvents = True`, improve code and should work.

Comment: Not sure what i'm doing wrong.... Step one is pasted in the "thisworkbook" section as well as above, in the sheet that i'm pasting step 2. I've changed the fields to some actual selections in the filter and it's not working or giving any errors

I've added my code above.

Comment: No exactly, place step 1 in new Module, not object module. Just insert new module and put `Public` declarations at the top

Comment: Before you place code 2. Create pivot table where you have in rows 'month' and 'week'. Than put the code into module which refers to sheet where you have your pivot table. Must work... Than try any changes with column titles